# Why do my pumpkin seeds unplant themselves?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am planting them above ground, on farmland, with nothing directly overhead to block the sunlight. I had 12 pumpkin seeds, and none of them stayed. Occasionally, they would pop out instead of simply disappearing, so I tried replanting them, this time with torches on fence posts next to them in addition to the abundant sunlight, to the same result every time. A couple of wheat seeds popped out too, but are now growing seemingly fine. I am completely out of pumpkin seeds now, though. I have the 0.16.05 version of PE on the Kindle Fire.

Comment: No problem. Note that you can press the checkmark next to an answer, to mark it as accepted, if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need water. Any block filled with water whether it is flowing or source block, will keep 9 x 9 area centered on that block hydrated. This will prevent seeds from popping out.

Answer (score 3):

**If your fields aren't irrigated, plants might uproot**. Try to put some water patches nearby or an irrigation ditch, using a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is a block of space on any side of the pumpkin-it doesn't have to be farmed land. pumpkins take 2 blocks to grow.